# how to explode a nested dictionary from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, explode

I'm trying to explode the genres column into a separate data frame with (id, name) as columns.

this is the data frame I'm working with
[image]

this is what I'm trying to achieve
[image]

i havent been able to find a solution on my own
what i have tried is to explode the genre

`genres = df['genres'].explode()`

Comment: Try `genres = pd.DataFrame(df.genres.explode().values.tolist())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) *constructor* :

```
#if need to evalute the column as lists of dict
#from ast import literal_eval
#df["genres"] = df["genres"].apply(literal_eval)

genres = pd.DataFrame(df.pop("genres").explode().tolist())
```